# How to implement a custom deserializer using serde that allows for parsing of untagged enums with non self-describing data format

Tags: rust, serde

I have a data format that I am currently using `serde` to parse. The actual format isn't important, but assume it's a string that looks like `key_value_also_value_key2_value2_key3_value3` where there's no way to distinguish between where values end and the next key start. I feel like this is what serde describes as a [non-self-describing data format](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html).

I have a working Deserializer that can take this code and parse it to a Struct (as the Struct fields can then be used to figure out where keys start and stop). The implementation looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Deserializer<'de> {
    // This string starts with the input data and when something has been read, it is removed from here
    input: &'de str,
}

impl<'de> Deserializer<'de> {
    pub fn from_str(input: &'de str) -> Self {
        Deserializer { input }
    }
}

impl<'de, 'a> de::Deserializer<'de> for &'a mut Deserializer<'de> {
    type Error = Error;

    /// Deserialize to a struct. This is currently the only thing we support as we need the struct so we can tell the field names apart
    fn deserialize_struct<V>(
        self,
        _name: &'static str,
        fields: &'static [&'static str],
        visitor: V,
    ) -> Result<V::Value>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        // Parses the string into a HashMap given the field names from the struct
        // the actual logic is not important
        let map = crate::parser::emission_factor_id_to_map(self.input, fields)?;

        // Then create a MapDeserializer that implements MapAccess so we can pass it to visitor.visit_map()
        let serializer: MapDeserializer<_, crate::Error> = MapDeserializer::new(map.into_iter());

        // This consumes the whole input string, so set it to "" afterwards.
        self.input = "";

        // And then it works
        visitor.visit_map(serializer)
    }

    // Serde forces us to implement a great many functions we'll never use - have them just throw an error.
    fn deserialize_any<V>(self, _visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        Err(crate::Error::Message(
            "Something unexpected happened - deserialize_any was called but it should never be"
                .to_string(),
        ))
    }

    forward_to_deserialize_any! {
        bool i8 i16 i32 i64 i128 u8 u16 u32 u64 u128 f32 f64 char str string
        bytes byte_buf option unit unit_struct newtype_struct seq tuple
        tuple_struct map enum identifier ignored_any
    }
}
```

So far so good. I now want to to allow this Deserializer to deserialize an [untagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) that could look like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    Foo(FooStruct),
    Bar(BarStruct),
}
```

However parsing this enums seems to go straight to `deserialize_any`, where I can't seem to figure out how to do any of my parsing. I have access to the input string, but no way to get the struct fields of the different enums, or to forward the call to `deserialize_struct`.

I can achieve the behaviour I expect by writing it myself outside of the context of the deserializer with something like the following code:

```rust
pub fn parse(input: &str){
    let foo = my_deserializer::from_str(&input);
    if let Ok(foo) = foo {
        return Ok(MyEnum::Foo(foo));
    }

    let bar = my_deserializer::from_str(&input);
    if let Ok(bar) = bar {
        return Ok(MyEnum::Bar(bar));
    }
    
    panic!();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the above inside my deserializer without having to implement the logic myself for each enum?

Comment: Do you not just need to add `#[serde(untagged)]` to `MyEnum`?

Comment: Ah, sorry @AricKuter - I forgot that part in my example here (but not when trying it out). I've updated the example to include that, but the issue is the same.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/b7be637e8cf73dcbea28c6ea960604371726171d/serde/src/private/de.rs#L295-L296) seems to be relevant. "Untagged and internally tagged enums are only supported in self-describing formats."
It looks like it's because the code that handles untagged enums parses out the structure and then looks to see which variant matches that structure, it doesn't attempt the parsing multiple times as in the case of your code.

Comment: Yes that's also the closest I've found. I was just hoping for something like an official docs page if it can't be done, and not just a code doc that might be out-of-date.